# Synchronous code blocking in Node.js working with complex operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a Node.js application that processes a large amount of data. It seems to block other tasks while it's working, leading to slow performance. How can I improve the performance of my Node.js app and prevent synchronous code from blocking other tasks?

Here's an example of the blocking function:

```js
function processData(data) {
  // Heavy processing
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Perform complex calculations
  }
}

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  const data = fetchData(); // Fetch a large amount of data
  processData(data);
  res.send('Data processed');
});
```

How can I refactor the `processData` function to be non-blocking and improve the overall performance of my Node.js application?

Comment: If your code is sync in nature then worker threads are an option. https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html